# Dynamic imports in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to import dynamic of a file by means of process.env.NODE_ENV to import a style sheet or another one in production or in development. I have made a condition to load it but it gives me an error Error in ./src/index.js
Syntax error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (13: 4) I guess this is not correct but ... how can I do it? I use create-react-app

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import App from './components/App';

import routes from './routes';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import initialState from './reducers/initialState';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    import './styles/index.css';
}else {
    import './styles/index.scss';
}
const store = configureStore(initialState);

ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
       <App />
   </Provider>,
   document.getElementById('root') 
);
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Use `require('./styles/index.scss')`? :) But perhaps this is more something that should be decided by your build / CI and not by code?

Comment: An alternate approach would be to `import './styles';` then change the extension-processing from `.css` to `.scss` for production vs development, or have an alias for it and change the alias based on environment. I personally try to avoid branching like this in application code because as this shows it's a question of build logic, not application logic. Using `require` and `import` in the same file won't work in the long run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Laoujin mentions in the comments, you'll want to use `require` in this scenario.

For example, here's how I configure access to my Redux store, based on `NODE_ENV`, which could be adjusted to suit your needs:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {};

function getStore () {
    const configureStore = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? require('./configure-store.prod').default
        : require('./configure-store.dev').default;
    return configureStore(INITIAL_STATE);
}

export default getStore();
```

Comment: Just save my complete day! Thank you so much! Using `create-react-app` you can eiher import a file by `import FakeData_MoviesComingSoon from '../data/coming-soon.json';`, which you'l never be able to separate _production_ / _!==production_ and (because of you! ;-) ) `FakeData: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? require('../data/coming-soon.json') : ''` allows me to import a BIG data file ONLY when I'm developing. Tx! Tx! Tx! Tx! Just reduce my built App from 750k to 131k !!