# Calling external js functions in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I added this script within index.html:

```
<script type="module">
    import {viewAllItemsInfo} from "https://localhost:8000/viewInfoHelper.js"
    let fn = viewAllItemsInfo("en");
</script>
```

This worked fine, but how can I achieve this within a react component?

I have the following useEffect hook to append the external js file within the app page itself.

```
export const useScript = (url: string) => {

    const scriptLoaded =() => {
        window.viewAllItemsInfo("en");
        //error: window.viewAllItemsInfo is not a function
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = url;
      script.async = true;
      script.type = "module";
      script.onload = () => scriptLoaded();
      
      // Append the script to the DOM
      document.head.appendChild(script);

      return () => {
        document.body.removeChild(script);
      };
    }, [url]);

};
```

So far I cannot make this work, seems that the loaded module does not attaches itself to the window object.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not put the import statement inside the component file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic imports in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740515/dynamic-imports-in-react)

Comment: @evolutionxbox when importing inside the component file, it throws the following error: The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script

Comment: What is your target environment?

Comment: "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.10.1"

Comment: That’s not the target environment